# Django: global variables in multi-connections

Tags: python, ajax, django, web, global

I developed a django web-application and I tested it in local.. good news, it works!

Know I am trying to move forward. I want to make it reachable via public Internet.. Bad news, it won't work!

The client-side interact with server using Ajax and execute some python script and get some result to display in the web page.

The problem is that my application/server can't handle multiple connexions!!

**I clarify:**

Mainly, the problem is that when more than one client are served (2 for ex.), each one will ask the server to run a python script and, because there is a lot of global variables in the script, the two clients will modify them simultaneously and than **bof!**

Can multi-threading be a solution? How?

PS: It's clear, I am newbie to web :-). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is clear, surely: you should not be using global variables. If you need to store state for a user, do it in the session or the database.

Comment: thanks!! could you give some details about "`do it in the session or the database.`" (links, tutos, examples) please?

Comment: Not without seeing more details about what you're actually doing.

Comment: ok, how to get a user key? (something to identify the connected user) thanks in advance

Comment: Erm, `request.user`? You should read the [auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/) and [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/) docs.